# Programmatically begin editing UITextField in another table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` with a `UITextField` in each cell. When I finish editing each text field, I'd like to programmatically begin editing of the text field in the next chronological cell.

In `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField)`, I'm resigning first responder of the text field, and programmatically scrolling to the next table view cell using `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(scrollIndexPath, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)`.

Is there a way to begin editing of the text field in the following cell?

Comment: you can make next `UITextField` first responder by sending `becomeFirstResponder` message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Suryakant noted in comments, as I figured out immediately after posting the question, I'm calling the following in `textFieldShouldReturn`:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)) as! CustomTableViewCell

cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textfield: UITextField, of cell: TableViewCell) {\n
        textfield.resignFirstResponder()\n
        let nextIndexpath = IndexPath(row: cell.indexPath.row + 1, section: \ncell.indexPath.section)
        if let nextcell = self.tableView(self.tableview, cellForRowAt: nextIndexpath) as?\n TableViewCell {\n
            nextcell.setSelected(true, animated: false)\n
            nextcell.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()\n
        }\n
    }\n

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cell as like below and begin first responder

```
let cell = calenderTableView .cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
```